# How to add new fields in my form if i select a specific radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to make a form where there is radio button selection for gender. Now there are two radio buttons MALE and FEMALE.

When any user select FEMALE a new radio buttons appeared (option only availible for FEMALEs)to ask if she is only child of her parents and then submit button ??

But when user selects the gender MALE then there are no option appeared(this option is only for FEMALEs)..just the submit button is there..

now how to do that??I have no idea so i haven't add code..

If there is any suggestion to use other language. Please tell me..

Comment: First try on your own then ask by posting your code

Comment: I do not know how to do that ...so how can i post my code..

Comment: Use JQuery onClick event to show and hide the element for displaying new radio button when female radio button get clicked. [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-selection-in-jquery.php)

Comment: Try to use jQuery html to create the radio button dynamically based on the onClick of the radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using jQuery. Here is the full code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#r1").click(function () {
        $(".text").show();
    });
    $("#r2").click(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
    });
});
</script>

<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="r1" value="female" onClick="getResults()">Female&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="r2" value="male">Male
<div class="text">
<br>Are you the only child?<br>
<input type="radio" name="only" value="yes" onClick="getResults()">Yes&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="only" value="no">No
</div>
<br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function maleFemaleCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('maleCheck').checked) {
        // hide other element
    }
    else {
        // show other element
    }
}
</script>

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:maleFemaleCheck();" id="maleCheck">Male</input>
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:maleFemaleCheck();" id="femaleCheck">Female</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are expecting, you might want to add certain elements when any particular radio is clicked, which you can do using the event 'onclick'. You may also include the form in a parent element, such as `div`, so that later on you can use the `appendChild` element. For example, try to run this code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>####</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <label for="female">FEMALE: </label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" onclick="makeRadio(parentElement);"><br />
            <label for="male">MALE: </label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male"><br />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//get parent element
var parentElement = document.getElementById('container');

//add the new elements
function makeRadio(pElement){  //pElement refers to the parent element
    var radioButton = document.createElement('input');
    radioButton.setAttribute('type' , 'radio');
    radioButton.setAttribute('id' , 'newRadio');

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.textContent = 'YES';
    label.setAttribute('for' , 'newRadio');

    pElement.appendChild(label);
    pElement.appendChild(radioButton);
}
```

Now similarly, you can work out a way to add more elements, just don't repeat this code again and again. This is just an example.

Way 2 :

If you don't want to add elements, you can include them in your markup but use CSS to hide them. And using something like:

`function showElement(){
     if(document.getElementById("#id of check box").checked)
            //show the hidden check box
}`

can also help.

Hope it helps:)